# Full screen height in Kwicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kwicks

how to make Kwicks height to 100%? I would have full screen slider.

demo: http://devsmash.com/projects/kwicks/2.2.x/examples/responsive

Comment: Please post some of code snippets you have tried so far.As the reference links might not exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should give Kwicks height 100 %

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>
        $().ready(function() {
            $('.kwicks').kwicks({
                maxSize : '100%', 
                behavior: 'menu'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

In case maxSize 100% didnt work use Size 100% and try. Hope it will work.

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle file and show me your code HTML CSS JS ?